# bar and hat only apply to certain letters

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm a beginner in `Mathematica`. Like shown in the image below, I'm trying to put hat and bar to some letters (I just want to write vector notation) but only some letters can have them. What's wrong with how I do?

[image]

If you could provide online resource that covers these syntax, that would be more appreciable. Thank you.

(**Environment**) { Mac OSX 10.7, Ubuntu 11.10, Ubuntu 10.10}, Mathematica 8.0.4 Student Edition

Comment: This would be more on-topic at [mathematica.se].

Comment: @rcollyer thanks, I didn't expect there was already a stackoverflow forum for Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OverHat` and `OverBar`:

```
OverHat /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

[image: Overhat characters]

```
OverBar /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

[image: Overbar characters]

Comment: thanks, I moved a question to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/bar-and-hat-only-apply-to-certain-letters. And your suggestion almost solves my issue but not perfectly. Please see the link if still interested.